# Attempting to install Realtek Card Reader Drivers

Tags: release-loki, drivers, asus, storage

I'm completely new to elementary OS and Linux in general, I've managed to overcome a few issues so far but this one has me stumped, despite googling all manner of solutions.

I believe (from the manufacturers website) that my Asus UX501V has a Realtek card reader. I've downloaded the Linux driver from here:

http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

I've navigated to the folder `rts_pstor` and with a right click opened it in terminal. I've then tried a `sudo make` command but end up with this output:

```
$ sudo make
[sudo] password for aaron:         
sed "s/RTSX_MK_TIME/`date +%y.%m.%d.%H.%M`/" timestamp.in > timestamp.h
cp -f ./define.release ./define.h
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-77-generic/build/ SUBDIRS= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:199: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic'
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Here is the output of "df -h" incase it's useful and "lspci -v". (I saw both asked for in another thread, sorry if that's not helpful).

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1.2G  9.6M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root  457G   35G  399G   9% /
tmpfs                            5.9G   95M  5.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2                   473M  125M  324M  28% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                   511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                            1.2G   44K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000

$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: dc000000-dd0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000c1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 70000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
    Kernel modules: i915_bpo

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Memory at dd410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at dd438000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd437000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPSS I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at dd436000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 135
    Memory at dd435000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at dd430000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at dd434000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at dd433000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: dd300000-dd3fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: dd200000-dd2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: c4000000-da0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000a1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3d, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: dd100000-dd1fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H PMC
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at dd42c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 136
    Memory at dd428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at dd400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-H SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at dd432000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
    Memory at dc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at dd000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro Device 6621
    Subsystem: Alcor Micro Device 6621
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at dd300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134
    Memory at dd200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot. It seems there are quite a few variations of my laptop with several different hardware configurations, particularly when it comes to minor things like the memory card reader.

I've checked and double checked and found that my laptop actually has an Alcor AU6621 model reader so the realtek driver would have done nothing anyway. Now I feel like a twit!

On further inspection that's actually mentioned in the outputs I posted above! I'm still looking for a way to get this working however, so if anyone has any tips I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing a similar problem, and after many searches, I found these links: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1270676 and https://github.com/josch09/ampe_stor. This driver claims to support AU6601, AU6621 and AU6625. You can clone this driver and install it to see if it worked. Unfortunately, it does not work for my AU6625 card reader (card detected, capacity ok, but failed to read any data)...